# Sitecore 7.2 Uninstall: Failed to Install Performance Counters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm trying to uninstall a sitecore project. It still shows up in the installed programs and when I try to remove it I get the following error message: Failed to install performance counters. (-2147024894). When I try to install using the name of the removed program I get an error saying that it could not open the ldf file for attach. It's looking for the ldf file in Database\MDF.

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am having the same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting the registry key containing the information about the previously installed instance under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Sitecore CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding deleting registry keys, I also had to delete some keys located under here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products`

Doing a "find" for the pesky `Sitecore` instance names helped me find this location.